# Use array destructuring (prefer-destructuring) error on eslint

Tags: eslint

here is the part of my code that eslint doesn't like.

```
this.attributes.mb.start_date = this.dateInstance.config.defaultDate.split('T')[0]
```

How can I rewrite it to overcome this error?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

eslint `prefer-destructuring` rule has two properties, `array` and `object`, can be used to turn on or off the destructuring requirement for each of those types independently. By default, both are true.

With array property enabled, this is incorrect

```
const foo = ['one', 'two'];

const x = foo[0];   // incorrect
```

The correct way to destructure an array is:

```
const [one, two] = foo;

console.log(one); // "one"
console.log(two); // "two"
```

as the rule says to access the element by destructuring the array, so let's say if you have a large array and you want to access `large array indices` directly, then the `array` property of this rule is not recommended to be enabled, as destructuring does not match this use case very well. You can simply put this in your `.eslintrc` to disable enforcing array destructuring in such cases:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "prefer-destructuring": ["error", {"object": true, "array": false}]
  }
}
```

Comment: Good advice.  Sometimes eslint is just in the way.  The prefer-destructuring rule basically doesn't fit for any large arrays?  Where "large" is more than 1, basically, because often I just want one or two of the array items destructured, not all of them.  Bleh, silliness.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the first value, and ignore all the others using deconstruction like this:

```
[this.attributes.mb.start_date, ] = this.dateInstance.config.defaultDate.split('T')
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on an official document from [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment),
The object and array literal expressions provide an easy way to create ad hoc packages of data.

```
const x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

here below declaration is invalid

```
const value = x[0] //invalid
```

The destructuring assignment uses a similar syntax, but on the left-hand side of the assignment to define what values to unpack from the sourced variable.

```
const x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const [y, z] = x;

console.log(y); // Expected output: 1
console.log(z); // Expected output: 2
```

Similarly, you can destructure objects on the left-hand side of the assignment.

```
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const { a, b } = obj;
// is equivalent to:
// const a = obj.a;
// const b = obj.b;
```